# GC overhead limit exceeded in Docker when trying to build project by sbt

Tags: scala, garbage-collection, docker, sbt, boot2docker

I am trying to build **sbt** project inside **docker** container and receiving such error:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

System specs:

- OS osx + boot2docker(8 gig RAM for virtual machine)
- ubuntu 15.10 inside docker container
- Oracle java 1.7 or Oracle java 1.8 or OpenJdk 1.8
- Scala version 2.11.6
- sbt version 0.13.8

It fails **only** if I am running **docker** build w/ **Dockerfile**. If I do it manually by logging to the container, it builds project w/o exception.

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=1G; support was removed in 8.0
sbt appears to be exiting abnormally.
The log file for this session is at /tmp/sbt4972348477806548245.log
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.resolve(UnixFileSystem.java:108)
    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:262)
    at java.io.File.listFiles(File.java:1290)
    at sbt.FilterFiles.handleFile(Path.scala:192)
    at sbt.DescendantOrSelfPathFinder.sbt$DescendantOrSelfPathFinder$$handleFileDescendant(Path.scala:204)
    at sbt.DescendantOrSelfPathFinder$$anonfun$sbt$DescendantOrSelfPathFinder$$handleFileDescendant$1.apply(Path.scala:206)
    at sbt.DescendantOrSelfPathFinder$$anonfun$sbt$DescendantOrSelfPathFinder$$handleFileDescendant$1.apply(Path.scala:205)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
    at sbt.DescendantOrSelfPathFinder.sbt$DescendantOrSelfPathFinder$$handleFileDescendant(Path.scala:205)
    at sbt.DescendantOrSelfPathFinder$$anonfun$sbt$DescendantOrSelfPathFinder$$handleFileDescendant$1.apply(Path.scala:206)
    at sbt.DescendantOrSelfPathFinder$$anonfun$sbt$DescendantOrSelfPathFinder$$handleFileDescendant$1.apply(Path.scala:205)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
    at sbt.DescendantOrSelfPathFinder.sbt$DescendantOrSelfPathFinder$$handleFileDescendant(Path.scala:205)
    at sbt.DescendantOrSelfPathFinder$$anonfun$sbt$DescendantOrSelfPathFinder$$handleFileDescendant$1.apply(Path.scala:206)
    at sbt.DescendantOrSelfPathFinder$$anonfun$sbt$DescendantOrSelfPathFinder$$handleFileDescendant$1.apply(Path.scala:205)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
    at sbt.DescendantOrSelfPathFinder.sbt$DescendantOrSelfPathFinder$$handleFileDescendant(Path.scala:205)
    at sbt.DescendantOrSelfPathFinder$$anonfun$sbt$DescendantOrSelfPathFinder$$handleFileDescendant$1.apply(Path.scala:206)
    at sbt.DescendantOrSelfPathFinder$$anonfun$sbt$DescendantOrSelfPathFinder$$handleFileDescendant$1.apply(Path.scala:205)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
    at sbt.DescendantOrSelfPathFinder.sbt$DescendantOrSelfPathFinder$$handleFileDescendant(Path.scala:205)
    at sbt.DescendantOrSelfPathFinder$$anonfun$sbt$DescendantOrSelfPathFinder$$handleFileDescendant$1.apply(Path.scala:206)
    at sbt.DescendantOrSelfPathFinder$$anonfun$sbt$DescendantOrSelfPathFinder$$handleFileDescendant$1.apply(Path.scala:205)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
    at sbt.DescendantOrSelfPathFinder.sbt$DescendantOrSelfPathFinder$$handleFileDescendant(Path.scala:205)
    at sbt.DescendantOrSelfPathFinder$$anonfun$sbt$DescendantOrSelfPathFinder$$handleFileDescendant$1.apply(Path.scala:206)
    at sbt.DescendantOrSelfPathFinder$$anonfun$sbt$DescendantOrSelfPathFinder$$handleFileDescendant$1.apply(Path.scala:205)
Error during sbt execution: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
2015/07/15 21:59:19 The command '/bin/sh -c /web/tools/bin/sbt compile' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Many thanks for any help!!1

Comment: can you add a reproducer, or share your Dockerfile ?

Comment: Unfortunately no, there are a lot of deps, protected by the company.

Comment: quite a pity, this is an interesting question, check https://plumbr.eu/outofmemoryerror/gc-overhead-limit-exceeded what is the value of Xmx (maximum heap size)?

Comment: try `strace docker build .` and look for mmap without munmap or a lot of brk with an argument always increasing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in sbt setting `USER someuser` and then running `sbt clean` under this user. The solution is in running `sbt clean` w/ next command `RUN runuser -l someuser -c 'sbt clean`.

---

was:

```
USER someuser
sbt clean
```

become:

```
runuser -l someuser -c 'sbt clean'
```

Comment: I hit this exact issue with sbt. I'm not sure why your fix works, or more specifically why USER doesn't work. Any explanation would be welcome